# Creating a family tree - How to add line for child?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I need to create a family tree and I'm using GoJS for this.

I have a father and mother, but also 2 sisters. One of my sister is the child of my father but isn't the child of my mother.

I need to create connections from the children to the parents and connections from the parent to the child.

I used basis code from template organization chart from site https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html

My current output is the following:

[image]

But actually, I need to change the output to this:
[image]

How can I modify the code to achieve this result?

```js
function init() {

  // Since 2.2 you can also author concise templates with method chaining instead of GraphObject.make
  // For details, see https://gojs.net/latest/intro/buildingObjects.html
  const $ = go.GraphObject.make; // for conciseness in defining templates

  myDiagram =
    new go.Diagram("myDiagramDiv", // must be the ID or reference to div
      {
        allowCopy: true,
        allowDelete: true,
        //initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
        maxSelectionCount: 1, // users can select only one part at a time
        validCycle: go.Diagram.CycleDestinationTree, // make sure users can only create trees
        "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { // allow double-click in background to create a new node
          name: "(new person)",
          title: "",
          comments: ""
        },
        "clickCreatingTool.insertPart": function(loc) { // method override must be function, not =>
          const node = go.ClickCreatingTool.prototype.insertPart.call(this, loc);
          if (node !== null) {
            this.diagram.select(node);
            this.diagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(node);
            this.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("NAMETB"));
          }
          return node;
        },
        layout: $(go.TreeLayout, {
          treeStyle: go.TreeLayout.StyleLastParents,
          arrangement: go.TreeLayout.ArrangementHorizontal,
          // properties for most of the tree:
          angle: 90,
          layerSpacing: 35,
          // properties for the "last parents":
          alternateAngle: 90,
          alternateLayerSpacing: 35,
          alternateAlignment: go.TreeLayout.AlignmentBus,
          alternateNodeSpacing: 20
        }),
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true // enable undo & redo
      });

  // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
  myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", e => {
    const button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
    if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
    const idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
    if (myDiagram.isModified) {
      if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
    } else {
      if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.slice(0, idx);
    }
  });


  //const levelColors = ["#AC193D", "#2672EC", "#8C0095", "#5133AB","#008299", "#D24726", "#008A00", "#094AB2"];
  const levelColors = ["#FFFFFF"];

  // override TreeLayout.commitNodes to also modify the background brush based on the tree depth level
  myDiagram.layout.commitNodes = function() { // method override must be function, not =>
    go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitNodes.call(this); // do the standard behavior
    // then go through all of the vertexes and set their corresponding node's Shape.fill
    // to a brush dependent on the TreeVertex.level value
    myDiagram.layout.network.vertexes.each(v => {
      if (v.node) {
        const level = v.level % (levelColors.length);
        const color = levelColors[level];
        const shape = v.node.findObject("SHAPE");
        if (shape) shape.stroke = $(go.Brush, "Linear", {
          0: color,
          1: go.Brush.lightenBy(color, 0.05),
          start: go.Spot.Left,
          end: go.Spot.Right
        });
      }
    });
  };
  //console.log(myDiagram.layout);
  // this is used to determine feedback during drags
  function mayWorkFor(node1, node2) {
    if (!(node1 instanceof go.Node)) return false; // must be a Node
    if (node1 === node2) return false; // cannot work for yourself
    if (node2.isInTreeOf(node1)) return false; // cannot work for someone who works for you
    return true;
  }

  // This function provides a common style for most of the TextBlocks.
  // Some of these values may be overridden in a particular TextBlock.
  function textStyle() {
    return {
      font: "8pt  Segoe UI,sans-serif",
      stroke: "white"
    };
  }

  // This converter is used by the Picture.
  function findHeadShot(pic) {
    if (!pic) return "images/HSnopic.png"; // There are only 16 images on the server
    return "images/HS" + pic;
  }

  // define the Node template
  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Spot", {
        selectionObjectName: "BODY",
        mouseEnter: (e, node) => node.findObject("BUTTON").opacity = node.findObject("BUTTONX").opacity = node.findObject("BUTTONC").opacity = 1,
        mouseLeave: (e, node) => node.findObject("BUTTON").opacity = node.findObject("BUTTONX").opacity = node.findObject("BUTTONC").opacity = 0,
        // handle dragging a Node onto a Node to (maybe) change the reporting relationship
        mouseDragEnter: (e, node, prev) => {
          const diagram = node.diagram;
          const selnode = diagram.selection.first();
          if (!mayWorkFor(selnode, node)) return;
          const shape = node.findObject("SHAPE");
          if (shape) {
            shape._prevFill = shape.fill; // remember the original brush
            shape.fill = "darkred";
          }
        },
        mouseDragLeave: (e, node, next) => {
          const shape = node.findObject("SHAPE");
          if (shape && shape._prevFill) {
            shape.fill = shape._prevFill; // restore the original brush
          }
        },
        mouseDrop: (e, node) => {
          const diagram = node.diagram;
          const selnode = diagram.selection.first(); // assume just one Node in selection
          if (mayWorkFor(selnode, node)) {
            // find any existing link into the selected node
            const link = selnode.findTreeParentLink();
            if (link !== null) { // reconnect any existing link
              link.fromNode = node;
            } else { // else create a new link
              diagram.toolManager.linkingTool.insertLink(node, node.port, selnode, selnode.port);
            }
          }
        }
      },
      // for sorting, have the Node.text be the data.name
      new go.Binding("text", "name"),
      // bind the Part.layerName to control the Node's layer depending on whether it isSelected
      new go.Binding("layerName", "isSelected", sel => sel ? "Foreground" : "").ofObject(),
      $(go.Panel, "Auto", {
          name: "BODY"
        },
        // define the node's outer shape
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
          name: "SHAPE",
          fill: "#39F",
          stroke: 'white',
          strokeWidth: 1.5,
          portId: ""
        }),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
          $(go.Picture, {
              name: "Picture",
              desiredSize: new go.Size(70, 70),
              margin: 1.5,
              source: "images/HSnopic.png" // the default image
            },
            new go.Binding("source", "pic", findHeadShot)),
          // define the panel where the text will appear
          $(go.Panel, "Table", {
              minSize: new go.Size(180, NaN),
              maxSize: new go.Size(200, NaN),
              margin: new go.Margin(6, 10, 0, 6),
              defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left
            },
            $(go.RowColumnDefinition, {
              column: 2,
              width: 4
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(), // the name
              {
                name: "NAMETB",
                row: 1,
                column: 0,
                columnSpan: 4,
                font: "10pt Segoe UI,sans-serif",
                editable: true,
                isMultiline: false,
                minSize: new go.Size(60, 16)
              },
              new go.Binding("text", "name").makeTwoWay()),
            $(go.TextBlock, "", textStyle(), {
              row: 2,
              column: 0
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(), {
                row: 2,
                column: 0,
                columnSpan: 4,
                editable: true,
                isMultiline: false,
                minSize: new go.Size(50, 14),
                margin: new go.Margin(0, 0, 0, 0)
              },
              new go.Binding("text", "title").makeTwoWay()),
            $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(), {
                row: 4,
                column: 0
              },
              new go.Binding("text", "key", v => "")),
            $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(), // the comments
              {
                row: 4,
                column: 0,
                columnSpan: 5,
                font: "8pt",
                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                editable: true, // by default newlines are allowed
                minSize: new go.Size(100, 14)
              },
              new go.Binding("text", "comments").makeTwoWay())
          ) // end Table Panel
        ) // end Horizontal Panel
      ), // end Auto Panel

      $("Button",
        $(go.Shape, "PlusLine", {
          width: 12,
          height: 12
        }), {
          name: "BUTTON",
          alignment: go.Spot.Right,
          opacity: 1, // initially not visible
          click: (e, button) => addEmployee(button.part)
        },
        // button is visible either when node is selected or on mouse-over
        new go.Binding("opacity", "isSelected", s => s ? 1 : 0).ofObject()
      ),

      // new Button for create children
      $("Button",
        $(go.Shape, "LineUp", {
          width: 12,
          height: 12
        }), {
          name: "BUTTONC",
          alignment: go.Spot.Left,
          opacity: 1, // initially not visible
          click: (e, button) => addEmployeeChild(button.part)
        },
        new go.Binding("opacity", "isSelected", s => s ? 1 : 0).ofObject()
        // button is visible either when node is selected or on mouse-over
      ),


      new go.Binding("isTreeExpanded").makeTwoWay(),
      $("TreeExpanderButton", {
          name: "BUTTONX",
          alignment: go.Spot.Bottom,
          opacity: 0, // initially not visible
          "_treeExpandedFigure": "TriangleUp",
          "_treeCollapsedFigure": "TriangleDown"
        },
        // button is visible either when node is selected or on mouse-over
        new go.Binding("opacity", "isSelected", s => s ? 1 : 0).ofObject()
      )
    ); // end Node, a Spot Panel

  function addEmployee(node) {
    if (!node) return;
    const thisemp = node.data;
    myDiagram.startTransaction("add employee");
    const newemp = {
      name: "(new person)",
      title: "(title)",
      comments: "",
      parent: thisemp.key
    };
    myDiagram.model.addNodeData(newemp);
    const newnode = myDiagram.findNodeForData(newemp);
    if (newnode) newnode.location = node.location;
    myDiagram.commitTransaction("add employee");
    myDiagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(newnode);
  }

  // New Function to children link
  function addEmployeeChild(node) {
    if (!node) return;
    const thisemp = node.data;
    myDiagram.startTransaction("add employee");
    const newemp = {
      name: "(new person)",
      title: "(title)",
      comments: "",
      child: thisemp.key
    };
    myDiagram.model.addNodeData(newemp);
    const newnode = myDiagram.findNodeForData(newemp);
    if (newnode) newnode.location = node.location;
    myDiagram.commitTransaction("add employee");
    myDiagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(newnode);
  }


  // the context menu allows users to make a position vacant,
  // remove a role and reassign the subtree, or remove a department
  myDiagram.nodeTemplate.contextMenu =
    $("ContextMenu",
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Add Employee"), {
          click: (e, button) => addEmployee(button.part.adornedPart)
        }
      ),
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Add Children"), {
          click: (e, button) => addEmployeeChild(button.part.adornedPart)
        }
      ),
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Vacate Position"), {
          click: (e, button) => {
            const node = button.part.adornedPart;
            if (node !== null) {
              const thisemp = node.data;
              myDiagram.startTransaction("vacate");
              // update the key, name, picture, and comments, but leave the title
              myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(thisemp, "name", "(Vacant)");
              myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(thisemp, "pic", "");
              myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(thisemp, "comments", "");
              myDiagram.commitTransaction("vacate");
            }
          }
        }
      ),
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Remove Role"), {
          click: (e, button) => {
            // reparent the subtree to this node's boss, then remove the node
            const node = button.part.adornedPart;
            if (node !== null) {
              myDiagram.startTransaction("reparent remove");
              const chl = node.findTreeChildrenNodes();
              // iterate through the children and set their parent key to our selected node's parent key
              while (chl.next()) {
                const emp = chl.value;
                myDiagram.model.setParentKeyForNodeData(emp.data, node.findTreeParentNode().data.key);
                //myDiagram.model.setChildrenKeyForNodeData(emp.data, node.findTreeChildrenNode().data.key);
              }
              // and now remove the selected node itself
              myDiagram.model.removeNodeData(node.data);
              myDiagram.commitTransaction("reparent remove");
            }
          }
        }
      ),
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Remove Department"), {
          click: (e, button) => {
            // remove the whole subtree, including the node itself
            const node = button.part.adornedPart;
            if (node !== null) {
              myDiagram.startTransaction("remove dept");
              myDiagram.removeParts(node.findTreeParts());
              myDiagram.commitTransaction("remove dept");
            }
          }
        }
      )
    );

  // define the Link template
  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link, go.Link.Orthogonal, {
        layerName: "Background",
        corner: 5
      },
      $(go.Shape, {
        strokeWidth: 1.2,
        stroke: "#FFFFFF"
      })); // the link shape

  // read in the JSON-format data from the "mySavedModel" element
  load();


  // support editing the properties of the selected person in HTML
  if (window.Inspector) myInspector = new Inspector("myInspector", myDiagram, {
    properties: {
      "key": {
        readOnly: true
      },
      "comments": {}
    }
  });

  // Setup zoom to fit button
  document.getElementById('zoomToFit').addEventListener('click', () => myDiagram.commandHandler.zoomToFit());

  document.getElementById('centerRoot').addEventListener('click', () => {
    myDiagram.scale = 1;
    myDiagram.commandHandler.scrollToPart(myDiagram.findNodeForKey(1));
  });
} // end init


// Show the diagram's model in JSON format
function save() {
  document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
  myDiagram.isModified = false;
}

function load() {
  myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
  go.Model.linkDataArray = [{
    to: "2",
    from: "20",
    color: "#FFF"
  }];
  // make sure new data keys are unique positive integers
  let lastkey = 1;
  myDiagram.model.makeUniqueKeyFunction = (model, data) => {
    let k = data.key || lastkey;
    while (model.findNodeDataForKey(k)) k++;
    data.key = lastkey = k;
    return k;
  };


}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/2.3.16/go.js" ></script>

<div id="myDiagramDiv"><canvas></canvas></div>
<div id="myInspector" class="myInspector">

</div>

<textarea class="d-none" id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%; height:270px;" class="form-control">
  { 
  "class": "go.TreeModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [
    {"key":1, "name":"I am", "title":"", "pic":"5.jpg"},
    {"key":2, "name":"Father", "title":"", "pic":"8.jpg", "parent":1},
    {"key":3, "name":"Mather", "title":"", "pic":"9.jpg", "parent":1},
    {"key":4, "name":"Sister", "title":"", "pic":"10.jpg","child":2},
 ]
}
</textarea>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit] scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and fix the code so it is a [mcve] - please change the textarea to just an inline object to make sure we can see the tree